# What is "thrown in for salt"

Tags: meaning-in-context

His voice drifted up, liquid and full of tears, mostly *Oh dear* with the occasional *Oh God* or *Now it's snow* "thrown in for salt".

What does "thrown in for salt" mean hear?

Answer (score 2):

"Thrown in for salt" is another way of saying "thrown in for good measure".  In this scenario, the author is saying that the subject throws in the occasional "Oh God" or "Now it's snow" for additional effect.

Comment: I believe you, but it would be good if you could add links or references.

Answer (score 2):

The use of this 'extra measure' by Walt Whitman is clearer than your passage quoted

> A melange of loafing, looking, hobbling, sitting, traveling— a little
>   thinking **thrown in for salt**, but very little — not only summer but all
>   seasons — —not only days but nights—some literary meditations—books,
>   authors examined, Carlyle, Poe, Emerson tried, (always under my
>   cedar-tree, in the open air, and never in the library)—mostly the
>   scenes everybody sees, but some of my own caprices, meditations,
>   egotism—truly an open air and mainly summer formation—singly, or in
>   clusters—wild and free and somewhat acrid—indeed more like cedar-plums
>   than you might guess at first glance. -Walt Whitman (1819–1892).  Prose Works. 1892.(I. Specimen Days 221. Cedar-Plums Like—Name)